# Windows server 2019 VM (Hyper-V) no access to internet

Tags: hyper-v, internet-connection, network-adapter, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows server 2012 computer hosting a Windows server 2019 server with Hyper-V but the Virtual Machine can't connect to the internet. The guest adapter is set up as External. I have other VMs with the same host, and problem is only with the Win 2019 VM.

I have installed Windows Integrated Services on both servers. I assume the Windows server 2012 is too outdated to host the 2019 server but I want to know if there is a workaround, thank you.

[image: Topology]

thank you guys, I guess its not possible :)

Comment: Is your Guest Adapter set up as External so that it is connected to your router?

Comment: Yes, as I do in my other vms, I'm only having issue in this case where it is a W srv 2012 hosting a w srv 2019, I never had this issue before. Perhaps windows server 2012 is too outdated to host a windows server 2019?

Comment: Welcome to SU. When asked for clarification or more info, please don't answer in comments, instead [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769788/edit) your question like I now did. Please verify the edit, and correct mistakes. I'd suggest adding the relevant configurations from the host and the guest as well. Please note, SE sites aren't discussion boards but Q&A sites, they work differently. I'd suggest taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the Asking- and Answering -sections in the {Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how things work here.

Comment: It appears Server 2019 is not supported as a Hyper-V guest running on Server 2012 .....   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97e42cf9-c37f-4639-b8a4-c907f0b28975/hyperv-windows-2012-r2-host-support-windows-2019-server-guest-os

Comment: They've easy rule to remember for this apparently: N-1  =  Whatever version the virtual machine is, it can run and be supported -1 host version.  So 2019 VM on 2016 host.  2016 VM on 2012R2 host.  etc. Nice rule easy to remember. But in your case it then may not/won't work.

Comment: should work, not supported doesn't mean doesn't work.  You may need to use a legacy NIC instead of the default.  Is this for a production system or home use?  Production, you need to upgrade your host, home/lab use, go for it.